# Insert a new ranking column bug

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, rank, insert-into, mysql-5.6

We have a table, TABLE_1:

```
 DATA
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 NULL
```

We want to generate a RANK column based on the DATA column

```
 DATA,RANK
 1,1
 2,2
 3,3
 4,4
 5,5
 NULL,0
```

The following is our code:

```
ALTER TABLE ` TABLE_1`

ADD COLUMN `RANK` DOUBLE NOT NULL AFTER `DATA`;

INSERT INTO TABLE_1

SELECT B.DATA,

CASE WHEN B.DATA IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE @number := @number + 1 

END RANK

FROM TABLE_1 B, (SELECT  @number := 0 AS BOO) C 

ORDER BY B.RANK;
```

The above query will only generate 0 in the RANK column

```
 DATA,RANK
 1,0
 2,0
 3,0
 4,0
 5,0
 NULL,0
```

However, if we just run the query along, without the ALTER TABLE and INSERT INTO like the following, HeidiSQL will return the table we are looking for

```
SELECT B.DATA,

CASE WHEN B.DATA IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE @number := @number + 1 

END RANK

FROM TABLE_1 B, (SELECT  @number := 0 AS BOO) C 

ORDER BY B.RANK;
```

The above script will generate a table we are looking for

```
 DATA,RANK
 1,1
 2,2
 3,3
 4,4
 5,5
 NULL,0
```

Could any guru enlighten why the ALTER TABLE/ INSERT INTO doesn’t work?

The SQL fiddle is available here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2837/2

Comment: It is not necessary to SHOUT YOUR QUESTION TITLE here. It will not get you help any faster, it makes the question more difficult to read, and it's rude and annoying to be SHOUTED at for no reason. It's clear your CAPS LOCK is not stuck, because you managed to properly case some of the text in your question itself. Please stop. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use update query with inner join

```
select * from bb;
    +------+
    | data |
    +------+
    |    1 |
    |    2 |
    |    3 |
    | NULL |
    +------+
    4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
    mysql> ALTER TABLE `bb`  ADD COLUMN `RANK` DOUBLE NOT NULL AFTER `DATA`;
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.72 sec)
    Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0


    mysql> UPDATE  bb INNER JOIN (SELECT B.DATA as data ,CASE WHEN B.DATA IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE @number := @number + 1 END RANK  FROM bb B, (SELECT  @number := 0 AS BOO) C ORDER BY B.RANK) TT ON TT.DATA=bb.data set bb.rank=TT.rank;
    Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.04 sec)
    Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

    mysql> select * from bb;
    +------+------+
    | data | RANK |
    +------+------+
    |    1 |    1 |
    |    2 |    2 |
    |    3 |    3 |
    | NULL |    0 |
    +------+------+
    4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Interesting solution! But will this slow down the query if a table is wide and big (a couple million rows)?

Comment: no the ranking logic will not have any considerable impact

Comment: The ranking in the real complicated case query behaves very weirdly.  I am thinking: "TT.DATA=bb.data" is equal to "TT.data=bb.data" in the example case?